# A problem with the evaluation of expressions using assumptions through Mathematica

Tags: simplifying-expressions, evaluation, algebraic-manipulation, assumptions

I want to evaluate the expression below,
$((2 (a_{01}+2 ya_{02}+x a_{11})^2+(b_{01}+2 y b_{02}+x b_{11})^2) (2 (a_{10}+y a_{11}+2 x a_{20})^2+(b_{10}+y b_{11}+2 x b_{20})^2))$,

at $x=-((2 (2 a_{02}a_{11} + b_{02}b_{11}))/(2 a_{11}^2 + b_{11}^2))y+\sigma$, assuming the following conditions,

$-(a_{11}b_{02}-a_{02}b_{11})^2 = 
 0$ and $- (-a_{20}b_{11}+a_{11}b_{20})^2 = 0$
.

To that end, I have been trying to employ Evaluation's command. However, Mathematica does not return a result, but rather an error message, as you may see in my attempts below.

```
Evaluate[((2 (a[0, 1] + 2 y a[0, 2] + x a[1, 1])^2 + (b[0, 1] + 
   2 y b[0, 2] + 
   x b[1, 1])^2) (2 (a[1, 0] + y a[1, 1] + 2 x a[2, 0])^2 + (b[1, 
    0] + y b[1, 1] + 2 x b[2, 0])^2)), x = (-((2 (2 a[0, 2] a[1, 1] + b[0, 2] b[1, 1]))/(
  2 a[1, 1]^2 + b[1, 1]^2)))*y + \[Sigma], Assuming -> -(a[1, 1] b[0, 2] - a[0, 2] b[1, 1])^2 = 0, -2 (-a[2, 0] b[1, 1] + a[1, 1] b[2, 0])^2 = 0]
(*Set: Tag Rule in Assuming->a[1,1] b[0,2]-a[0,2] b[1,1] is Protected.*)
(*Set:Tag Plus in -a[2,0]\ b[1,1]+a[1,1]\ b[2,0] is Protected*)
```

Bearing this in mind, How may I evaluate that equation under the conditions specified above?

Comment: Equations use `Equal` (i.e., `==`) rather than `Set` (i.e., `=`). `Assumptions` is an option, `Assuming` is a function. Where did the expression that includes `\[Sigma]` come from? It wasn't in the problem statement. `Evaluate` doesn't mean what you apparently think it does. Re-read its documentation.

Comment: it is not very clear, what you want to achieve in the end. Maybe you explain what kind of simplification do you expect here?

Comment: @BobHanlon. Hi, Bob. I hope you are doing well. Thanks for the observation. I have edited my question based on your comment. I want to evaluate that equation at $x=(-((2 (2 a_{02} a_{11}+b_{02}b_{11}))/(2 a_{11}^2+b_{11}^2)))*y+\sigma$.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch. Hi Alexei. As I have just mentioned above, I have just edited my question. My goal is to evaluate that equation at $x=(-((2 (2 a_{02} a_{11}+b_{02}b_{11}))/(2 a_{11}^2+b_{11}^2)))*y+\sigma$ under the conditions outlined above. Thanks for your observation.

Answer (score 3):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

Display the indexed variables as subscripts using [`Format`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format.html)

```
(Format[#[n__]] := Subscript[#, Row[{n}]]) & /@ {a, b};

expr = ((2 (a[0, 1] + 2 y a[0, 2] + x a[1, 1])^2 + (b[0, 1] + 2 y b[0, 2] + 
         x b[1, 1])^2) (2 (a[1, 0] + y a[1, 1] + 2 x a[2, 0])^2 + (b[1, 0] + 
         y b[1, 1] + 2 x b[2, 0])^2));

xVal = x -> (-((2 (2 a[0, 2] a[1, 1] + b[0, 2] b[1, 1]))/(2 a[1, 1]^2 + 
           b[1, 1]^2)))*y + σ;

assume = {-(a[1, 1] b[0, 2] - a[0, 2] b[1, 1])^2 == 
    0, -(-a[2, 0] b[1, 1] + a[1, 1] b[2, 0])^2 == 0};
```

Using the [`Assumptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions.html) with [`Simplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html)

```
expr2 = Simplify[expr /. xVal, Assumptions -> assume]
```

[image]

```
LeafCount /@ {expr /. xVal, expr2}

(* {215, 207} *)
```

This had limited effect.

Using an alternate approach, the two assumptions can be used to eliminate two variables

```
vars = Cases[assume, _a | _b, All]
```

[image]

The possible replacements are

```
(solns = First /@ ((Solve[assume, #] & /@ Subsets[vars, {2}]) /. {} -> 
       Nothing)) // Short[#, 3] &
```

[image]

Using brute force to find the replacement that provides the best simplification

```
{repl, expr3} = MinimalBy[Select[{#, Simplify[expr2 /. #]} & /@ solns,
     FreeQ[#, Indeterminate] &] // Quiet, LeafCount[#[[2]]] &][[1]]
```

[image]

`expr2` and `expr3` are equivalent with the replacements derived from the assumptions

```
expr2 == expr3 /. repl // Simplify

(* True *)
```

The simplification is significant

```
LeafCount /@ {expr2, expr3}

(* {207, 107} *)
```